# Rails 3 Form File Handling Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a Rails 3 application with a pretty standard multipart form that includes an image upload. However, it throws an error.

The form starts with:

```
<%= form_for(@object, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :photo %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit Object' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then, I have this in the object.rb model:

```
def photo=(file_data)
  unless file_data.blank
    @file_data = file_data
    self.extension = file_data.original_filename.split('.').last.downcase
  end
end
```

This throws the following error:

> undefined method `blank' for #ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x37ecc78

Meanwhile, it also shows the image exists in the Request Parameters error page:

> "photo"=>#ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x37ecc78 @original_filename="Image.jpg",

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blank` method doesn't exist. It's `blank?`, with the question mark.

```
unless file_data.blank?
  ...
```

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)

Comment: Oh, man! I spent so long looking at it, how could I have missed that?! Thanks!